# Get the coordinates of a particular div with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ionic-framework

I am trying to get the coordinates of a div with JQuery. I have two projects; a web form and an Ionic Framework html page. Both projects have the following code snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#draw_area").click(function(e) {
    var parentOffset = $(this).parent().offset();
    var relX = e.pageX - parentOffset.left;
    var relY = e.pageY - parentOffset.top;
    alert("pixel " + relX + ', ' + relY)
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ClsdrawArea" id="draw_area" style="width: 900px; height:900px; background-image: url('images/PathFindingMap.png'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover; border: 1px solid red;"></div>
```

Unfortunately, both projects give me different coordinates when I click on the same x y position on the same image (the pathfindingMap image). 
What I want is to get the same coordinates. Can anyone please tell me how I could achieve this? Thanks!

**EDIT**:
In my web form's client side, there is no any html element except the "draw_area" div and using parentOffset.left and parentOffset.top, both give me the value "0". On the other hand, in my ionic framework html page, it has the following code on top of the "draw_area" div:

```
 <ion-view view-title="">

        <ion-content >
  <ion-scroll zooming="true" overflow-scroll="false" direction="xy" style="width: 100%; height:100%;"
                        scrollbar-x="true" scrollbar-y="true">
```

And using parentOffset.left gives me the value "0" but parentOffset.top gives me the value "92".

Is there an alternative method using JQuery to get the same coordinates for the "draw_area' div of both projects? Thanks!

Comment: Why are you going up to the parent in the first place?

Comment: Hi, I just realised that I am not supposed to use the parent in the first place. But I do not know any alternative solution. Can you tell me please?

Comment: Don’t get the offsets of the parent, but the element itself?